# Funcionamiento del motor de AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

No entiendo la imagen descriptiva del funcionamiento de AJAX que pego más abajo.

Supongo que al hacer el primer input se solicita una página web. El motor de AJAX cursa la petición al servidor.
Entonces, hasta que el servidor procesa la solicitud, no debería haber ningún display. ¿Qué hace el display ahí antes de que el servidor devuelva la página?

¿Cual de los display es la comunicación de los datos recibidos para recarga parcial de la página solicitada en el input2?
¿Por qué no se muestra inmediatamente a continuación?

¿Alguien puede echarme una mano para entenderlo?

Muchas gracias

[image: Modelo de funcionamiento de AJAX]

[image: Mi interpretación de cómo funciona.]

Comment: La verdad es que esas imágenes no ayudan mucho a entender el concepto :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax trabaja bajo un modelo asíncrono, lo que significa que si haces varias llamadas estas se ejecutan en paralelo, lo que puede ocasionar que el orden de las respuestas no sea el mismo que el de las llamadas.
Dicho esto puedes recibir la respuesta de la llamada 2 antes de que termine la llamada 1, y hacer el display sin tener que esperar la llamada 1.

La imagen representa algo muy general, el display puede ser cualquier cosa, un loader o alguna otra operación en javascript, lo que trata de comunicar es que las llamadas no bloquean la operación de tu programa.